# How do I delete a blocked IP?

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to remove a blocked IP from our server.

```
405 35964 DROP       all  --  !lo    *       IP ADDRESS           0.0.0.0/0 
 19   988 DROP       all  --  *      !lo     0.0.0.0/0            24.7.56.95 


root@host01 [~]# iptables -D INPUT 35964
iptables: Index of deletion too big
root@host01 [~]# iptables -D INPUT 405
iptables: Index of deletion too big

root@host01 [~]# iptables -D INPUT -s IPADDRESS -j ACCEPT
iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?)
```

What gives?!  Google is of no help since I keep finding the same lines that give me the same error.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Run `iptables-save|grep 24.7.56.95` to get the exact rule command used to enabled the block. It will be something like:

`-A INPUT ! -i lo -s 24.7.56.95 -j DROP`

Take this command, replace the `-A` with `-D` and run it through `iptables`:

`iptables -D INPUT ! -i lo -s 24.7.56.95 -j DROP`

Et viola!

Answer (score 4):

Use `iptables -D INPUT 1` to delete the first rule in list, or `iptables -F INPUT` to delete *all* rules.

---

405 and 35964 are the packet and byte counts, respectively. Just like the header says.

```
$ sudo iptables -v -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 155 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Use `iptables -L --line-numbers` to see the actual rule numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is any block for the IP address in csf

## grep  /etc/csf

If found, remove that csf rule

## csf -dr

It will automatically remove the iptable rule also.

You can check the status of IP using the command csf -g

If no rules in Ip tables, the result will be as follows:

Chain            num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
No matches found for  in iptables

You can also check the same in IP table also.

## iptables -nL | grep