# unban or unblock IP-address from fail2ban and iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall, fail2ban, ufw

Fail2ban blocked an IP-address which I would like to undo. I have When I run `sudo fail2ban-client set sshd unbanip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` (where the xx-part is the IP-address) I get a response:

> NOK: ('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is not banned',)
>   xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is not banned

I have been reading about similar issues [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/384230/fail2ban-unblock-ipaddress) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/332247/how-do-i-delete-a-blocked-ip), but I am still having issues. When I run `iptables-save|grep xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` I can find the rule in iptables blocking the address:

> -A ufw-user-input -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreacable.

Now though, when I try `sudo iptables -D INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` I get the response:

> iptables: Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).

I tried adding the `/32` part to the ipaddress, i tried `ufw-user-input` instead of `INPUT`, but each and every time I get the same error.

Now my question is: what can I do to get rid of the rule? And also, what could be the reason that fail2ban is telling me the address is not banned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command you give `iptables -D INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is querying the INPUT chain but your rule is stored in the `ufw-user-input` chain of iptables. If you were to give the command `sudo iptables -L` you would see all chains and one of them would be `ufw-user-input` and under that one your offending rule should be placed.

To delete that one you can either do `sudo iptables -D ufw-user-input -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` or use `ufw status`, find the corresponding rule and use `ufw delete $RULE`

Comment: your first suggestion was one I already tried and did not work. Your second suggestion did the trick though!